# Why do I need to set constraint constant after some delay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I am adding a view programatically and changing constant of height constraint but it does not set the width as the screen width in viewDidLoad method. But width perfectly set when put those line in after 0.2 seconds delay queue.

Below is my Code

Added In ViewDidLoad

`dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cAreaView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"aView" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [_vwComplaintArea addSubview:cAreaView];
        [self setConstraintLayout:cAreaView toVw:_vwComplaintArea];
        [_firstViewHeightConstraint setConstant:_firstViewHeightConstraint.constant + cAreaView.bounds.size.height];
        [_heightForComplaintARe setConstant:cAreaView.bounds.size.height];
    });`

`-(void)setConstraintLayout:(UIView *)vw toVw:(UIView *)toVw
{
    [vw autoSetDimensionsToSize:CGSizeMake(toVw.bounds.size.width, vw.bounds.size.height)];
    [vw autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeTop ofView:toVw];
    [vw autoPinEdge:ALEdgeLeft toEdge:ALEdgeLeft ofView:toVw];
}`

Can anyone suggest the best way to set constraints programatically in viewDidLoad.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to set constraint in viewWillAppear.

Comment: But it showing some animation of changing height of View. I dont want any kind of animation there.

Comment: Could you provide yours code that not working and working?

Comment: add your code in question what you have tried!

Comment: add it in question!!! not in comment!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to override `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. In `viewDidLoad` you should only add elements to you view from xib, any manipulation for the frame should occur in view will and did layout subviews. It has to do something with view cycle.

Per documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews

> When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view
>   adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this
>   method.

On this event, you will have the correct situation about screen and distances so you can update constraints and frames accordingly.

Comment: Yes. He don't need to override `viewWill/DidLayoutSubviews`. It would needed if he used frames instead of autolayout.

Comment: I am trying to add a view in subview and adding constraint also. Can I do the same in viewDidLayoutSubviews method? @Cy-4AH

Comment: yeah, especially if you are setting frame for the view. Again, I would add that view in viewDidLoad, as you did, and set the frame and/or constraints in viewDidLayoutSubviews. 

@Cy-4AH so this solution won't work?

Comment: But @nick when I try to add constrain in viewDidLayoutSubviews then it will add again and again when it calls and it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can change constraint constant at any time you wish. But as I understood, you are trying to set constant equal to `view` width value, taken from `view`'s `frame` or `bounds` property. You need to know, that in `viewDidLoad` this properties don't have actual values since you use autolayout; they will get actual values in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method (note that it can be called multiple times). When you add delay for 0.2 sec, autolayout processes already finished, thats why you get right result. So, you can assign constraint constant in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, OR better just add new constraint for equal width's:

```
let someProportion: CGFloat = 2
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: yourView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: someProportion, constant: 0))
```

Comment: will it not add constarint many times in viewDidLayoutSubviews??

Comment: @ManishPatel you should take care about it. you absolutely shouldn't create new constraints in viewDidLayoutSubviews, you may only change constants for existing (created in viewDidLoad for example) constraints. You need provide code, that will be flexable and will not depends on previous constant value

Comment: @ManishPatel but as I said, since you use autolayout, you better rethink your sizes logic and make new equality constraints, without any manipulation with frames/bounds.

Answer (score -1):

Don't set your constraints in `viewDidLoad`. Instead set them in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. So that your app will have all the components loaded for applying constraints.